# Tuning tcp_keepalive_time for Node.js leak

Tags: tcp, node.js, socket, keep-alive, file-descriptors

I'm currently having a socket leak with my Node.js application. 
This bug is also posted [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3613).
I hope to fix this soon. CLOSE_WAIT and FIN_WAIT2 seem to be the major problem.

```
Connections:    1662
ESTABLISHED:    238
CLOSE_WAIT:     770
FIN_WAIT1:      4
FIN_WAIT2:      632
```

The following data is retrieved by entering (alternatives like) this:

```
netstat -anp | grep ${node_pid} | wc -l
```

I've read that you can solve this by tuning these variables:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout    ( = 60 )
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time ( = 7200 )
```

Although my tcp_fin_timeout is set to 60 seconds, my sockets keep being there for more than 60 seconds. That's why I think I should tune the `tcp_keepalive_time`.

It's hosted on a Linux Centos 5 server which is also running Apache and MySQL.

Can I easily decrease `tcp_keepalive_time` to something like 1800, or will it have negative impacts on Apache, for example?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options you can tune to save on server resources relating to connection. See [this page](http://null.53bits.co.uk/index.php?page=kernel-ip-tuning) for a couple of of the options and their description. Also, see the list of refernces at the end of that page:

```
man 7 ip
man 7 tcp
http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap6sec70.html
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html
```

You can reduce the tcp_fin_timeout to say 20, as this is solving a problem that arises at the end of a connections lifetime/requirement. The same for the tcp_keepalive_time, if you bring it down to a sensible value and not too low (say 600, when used with tcp_keepalive_intvl and tcp_keepalive_probes).

There shouldn't be any negative effects with your Apache server as typical web HTTP traffic is very bursty and short lived. Unless a user is downloading a large file over a link with very high packet loss, in which case, accessing your site would be the least of their worries.

If you just read the man pages and those links it should become pretty (any confusion, post a question here obviously!).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will see into this later when I have time!